# Import GoPro (or similar) video segments in one step into DaVinci Resolve in the correct order

Tags: davinci-resolve

GoPro saves video files in 4Gig segments, on my settings that's 5mins, 20 seconds per segment. That means after an hour of recording there would be 12 files.

The format is

```
GXSSVVVV.mp4
```

where SS is the segment number and VVVV is the video number, one video is multiple segments. Example:

```
GX010010.mp4
GX010011.mp4
GX010012.mp4
GX020010.mp4
GX020011.mp4
GX020012.mp4
GX030010.mp4
GX030012.mp4
GX040010.mp4
```

This means there 3 videos.

```
video: #10 = GX010010.mp4 + GX020010.mp4 + GX030010.mp4 + GX040010.mp4
video: #11 = GX010011.mp4 + GX020011.mp4
video: #12 = GX010012.mp4 + GX020012.mp4 + GX030012.mp4
```

Is it is, to put all of the videos in order into DaVinci Resolve's timeline I drag each segment, one at a time into the timeline.

Is there a way to add all the segments into the timeline in order **in one step**?  Ideally I just want to select all the segments in Windows Explorer (or the Finder) or the Media Library and drag them to the timeline and have DaVinci Resolve order them correctly.

Answer (score 1):

As I was typing the question I think I figured it out.

Import all the clips into the Media Pool, sort by "date created" or "date modified" so the oldest is at the top.

[image]

Select all the clips, drag into the timeline

[image]

It appears they are all in the correct order